# mysql query magento consecutive left join problem

Tags: mysql, sql, select, magento-1.9

I have this query that doesn't give me the expected results from the magento 1.9 database:

```
SELECT 
customer.email AS email,
company.value as comp

FROM customer_entity AS customer

JOIN customer_address_entity AS addressentity
    ON customer.entity_id=addressentity.parent_id

LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar AS company
    ON  company.entity_id=addressentity.entity_id
WHERE
    customer.store_id = 1 AND

    company.attribute_id=24 AND

    customer.email="this@mail.com"
```

It should give me the email and the company value as null if it doesn't exist but it give me nothing if there is no company name.

Answer (score 1):

Please use left outer join for customer_address_entity table as well,

```
SELECT 
customer.email AS email,
company.value as comp

FROM customer_entity AS customer

FULL OUTER JOIN customer_address_entity AS addressentity
    ON customer.entity_id=addressentity.parent_id

FULL OUTER JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar AS company
    ON  company.entity_id=addressentity.entity_id;
```

Comment: Then please full outer join, you may have it the first table. Edited the query. Please try. And do not use where clause, it fill filter out your data resulting no values

Comment: Mysql doesn't use FULL OUTER JOIN, I tried with union and it is not the expected result.